# Giving the simplex category the structure of a site to define Kan complexes as sheaves.

Tags: simplicial-stuff, topos-theory, simplicial-complex

I'll get straight to the point: the simplex category $\Delta$ can be given the structure of a site by defining $S$ to be a sieve on an object $[n]$ if all morphisms selected by $S$ are injective on set level and if the union of their images as functions of sets equals $[n]$.

Then sheaves $F$ on $\Delta$ are simplicial sets. The locality condition of a sheaf on $\Delta$ corresponds to faces of $F$ being uniquely defined by the faces that they are attached to. I.e if we have faces $f,f' \in F[n]$ with $d_i(f)=d_i(f')$ for all $i$ then $f = f'$.

I don't really know what to make of this if I want to prove that all Kan complexes are sheaves and all sheaves are Kan complexes though or if the injective condition on the morphisms selected by the sieves is even needed

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Definitely not all Kan complexes satisfy this "rigidity"condition, I think the ones that do are really rare actually

Comment: Kan complexes are not like sheaves because the horn-filling condition is just an _existence_ property, without any _uniqueness_.  The category of Kan complexes is not equivalent to any category of sheaves (for instance, it doesn't have coequalizers, exactly because of the lack of uniqueness when filling horns).

Comment: @EricWofsey Ok, but is the category of Kan complexes a Grothendieck topos?

Comment: No, any Grothendieck topos has coequalizers.

Comment: @EricWofsey So you are saying that the category of Kan complexes does not have coequalizers?

Comment: Yes, I said that in my first comment.

Comment: I was just trying to avoid confusion, maybe you meant that the coequalizer of morphisms of Kan complexes in the category of simplicial sets is not necessarily a Kan complex. Which is different from the statement that the category whose objects are Kan complexes doesn't have coequalizers. Do you have a reference for this fact?